# Capture playing video from flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

Are there any way to capture only playing video from flash player to another flash player or html5 video player? (for example: embed youtube player to custom player with different controls and design)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started) ... Specifically, you embed a "chromeless" youtube player in your app. Then you can add your own Flash or HTML UI to control playback.

It's possible other video services allow this. You just need to check their API documentation to see if it's possible.

Comment: Ok, but what about services without API?

Comment: Generally, they don't let you that. Your question seems a bit ambiguous as to what you want. The title says capture a video (like saving to disk), and none of those services have an a pi to do that (though its possible, I can't help). But then you say you want to embed a you tube video. You can use the YouTube a pi to do that. If you don't want to, then you need to get more expertise than what I can offer. Clarify what it is you want and good luck :)